# Inputting a coordinate into blackberry Z10 via native maps

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, blackberry-10, geo

in iphone, we can use
maps:daddr=&saddr=;
to map directions between two points via apple native maps,

in android we can use
geo:

in blackberry, if i use maps:, i can call out the native maps, with current location centered. 
But can't get directions between two points, is there any certain syntax that should be used to retrieve directions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for draw route in map.. Hope this will helpful for you.

For more detail check [RouteMapInvoker](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__platform__routemapinvoker.html)

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.platform 1.0

Page {
  content: Container {
     layout: DockLayout {}

     attachedObjects:[ 
        RouteMapInvoker {
           id: routeInvokerID

           // This example shows binding properties to pre-defined values
           // For example, you can request a route from Ottawa to Toronto,
           // avoiding the highways.

           // You can bind properties to values coming from other widgets
           // within this QML page (for example, text field's input)
           startLatitude    :  45.416667         // Ottawa's latitude
           startLongitude   : -75.7              // Ottawa's longitude
           startName        : "Ottawa, Ontario"
           startDescription : "Canada's capital"

           endLatitude      : 43.652527          // Toronto's latitude
           endLongitude     : -79.381961         // Toronto's longitude
           endName          : "Toronto, Ontario"
           endDescription   : "My trip's destination"

           // Specify any extra route options...
           avoidHighwaysEnabled : true

           // Specify what should be the center of the map.
           centerLatitude : 44.4555
           centerLongitude : -77.7744
           // 'heading' property is not explicitly set,
           // so it will be: 0 (i.e., facing North).

        }
     ]

     // Make a Cascades button (or any Cascades widget)
     // that can be used to trigger route invoker.
     Button {           
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

        text: "Get route"

         // When button is clicked, call the invoker by its ID
         onClicked: {
            routeInvokerID.go();
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but this is a phonegap app, so im trying to see if there is an HTML/JS approach, or a webworks method of working around this.